# Change Dashboard menu position?

Tags: customization

I am trying to put three menu items before the `Dashboard` menu item in admin dashboard.
Problem is that `Dashboard` has menu position `2`.

I can manage to put in two menu items before with position `0` and `1`, but `2` collides with Dashboard.

So my thought was to move the Dashboard position. Is this possible?
Can I change `Dashboard` menu position from `2` to something else (like 3, 4 or 5)?

Is there a hook for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can reorder admin menu items like this, notice I moved index.php (dashboard) to the bottom.

```
function my_custom_menu_order($menu_ord) {
    if (!$menu_ord) return true;

    return array(
        'separator1', // First separator
        'edit.php', // Posts
        'upload.php', // Media
        'link-manager.php', // Links
        'edit-comments.php', // Comments
        'edit.php?post_type=page', // Pages
        'separator2', // Second separator
        'themes.php', // Appearance
        'plugins.php', // Plugins
        'users.php', // Users
        'tools.php', // Tools
        'options-general.php', // Settings
        'separator-last', // Last separator
        'index.php', // Dashboard
    );
}

add_filter( 'custom_menu_order', 'my_custom_menu_order', 10, 1 );
add_filter( 'menu_order', 'my_custom_menu_order', 10, 1 );
```

---

If you need to move menu items created manually or by a plugin you can get the correct value to add to the array by debugging like so...

```
function debug_admin_menu_items() {
    echo '<pre>' . print_r( $GLOBALS[ 'menu' ], TRUE) . '</pre>';
}

add_action( 'admin_init', 'debug_admin_menu_items' );
```

*Note: The above code goes in your theme's functions.php*

Answer (score 0):

Go to screen Options and Install plugin **Wp Admin UI Customize** then you can change any thing in dashboard.